# Cloth Simulation not following character movement

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

I am new to cloth simulation, especially for characters, I tried using a model from sketchfab, rigging and getting a simple animation from mixamo and tried using cloth simulation in it, I can't seem to get the cloth to follow the character at all. I tried watching a video that mentioned to first reset the character pose, then move the animation for a bit to help the cloth catch upto the animation, but in my case it just keeps on going. I have attached the model as well. [image]

NSFW may be a bit NSFW, I got if off sketchfab, I have tried adding some censor

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coat won't follow the body with the cloth simulation only, it would be too complicated to calculate, you need to parent the coat to the armature *With Automatic Weight* and put the *Armature* modifier above the *Cloth* modifier, also delete the bake (and maybe increase the *Simulation End* frame if you want the simulation to go beyond 100 frames). You'll still need to tweak some parameters, clean the topology, create a pin group, etc. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg) is a good tutorial about cloth.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that tutorial I wanted to recommend as well :) Apart from the cloth not being moved by the character itself, there are some other issues. The totpology of the coat is horrible, the coat mesh gets intersected by the body in multiple areas, and there are some loose parts on the sleeves which are not connected to the rest of the coat so they will simply fall down (well, maybe not if they get parented to the armature, but I doubt they will stay on the coat where they are supposed to be when being deformed by bones).

Comment: Sure, there are mutliple problems, I just wanted to point out the main one

Comment: No criticism, just adding to your answer which saved me from writing my own ;) And following the linked tutorial these additions will all become obvious anyway.